# Assert.Equals of Two objects implementing IEquatable(T) doesn't use the equals method

Tags: .net, mstest

I have a custom type Type that implement IEquatable(Type).
Then I new up two instances of the type, none of them are Null

```
Assert.IsTrue(obj1.equals(obj2)) //Success
Assert.AreEqual(obj1, obj2) //False
Assert.AreEqual(Type)(obj1, obj2) //False
```

The first one hits my equals, the second one hits the ToString()
Any suggestions?

**update**
some code to illustrate: http://pastebin.com/1uecrfeW

**more update**
If I have to override the base equals, even if a better (generic) equals is available, then what's the use of implementing IEquals(T)?

Comment: Read this [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx). Everything is clarified in remarks

Comment: You didn't override `Object.Equals`

Comment: Re your edit - the genres version is used commonly by generic code - List-of-T etc. Also, by EqualityComparer-of-T etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that it's *actually* hitting `Equals(object)` instead of `Equals(T)`. If you haven't overridden `Equals(object)` then it's probably failing the assertion, which then uses `ToString` to create a useful failure message.

If you could show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem (including which `Assert` method you're calling - NUnit? Something else?) that would help.

Comment: @borisCallens: As I thought - you've provided `Equals(Sentence)` but not `Equals(object)`. In C# that would have given an error as you can't override `GetHashCode` without also overriding `Equals(object)`.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC Assert.AreEqual is non-generic, so only object.Equals applies; try checking the override of non-generic object.Equals.

In addition to the inconvenience of calling a generic method via reflection, the objects could also implement *multiple* `IEquatable<T>` (for different T). So the non-generic version makes sense here, IMO.

Comment: @boris even if there is a generic method, generic type inference depends on the compilers view of the types of the *parameters* types - not the values. What are the variables typed as? Note: changing them to `dynamic` would probably fix it, for hacky values of "fix"

Comment: I inline newed them up as Type's

Comment: @boris I have no idea what you mean by that statement. Showing the code that declares then would help

Comment: Assert.AreEqual<Type>(new Type(), new Type())

Comment: @boris and does `Type : IEquatable<Type>`

Comment: Yes, that's my opening statement ;) I added a link to some example code in the OP

Comment: @boris well, it could do either; while it *could* use the generic API it is not *obliged* to...