# Assert.AreEquals calls object.Equals irrespective of IEquatable implemenations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Today when writing and running some tests, I found out that even though my class implemented an `IEquatable<MyClass>` interface, an `Assert.AreEqual(instanceOfMyClass, anotherInstance);` resulted in false.

It turns out that no matter what, the `Assert.AreEquals` calls `object.Equals(object obj)` instead of the correct `MyClass.Equals(MyClass obj)` function.

Under the assumption that there is a logical reason, what is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assert.Equals of Two objects implementing IEquatable(T) doesn't use the equals method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320666/assert-equals-of-two-objects-implementing-iequatablet-doesnt-use-the-equals-m)

Answer (score 2):

You could try overloading == on the class in question and use the generic "Assert.AreEqual< T>" overload which uses the equals operator.

Personally I would prefer to use `Assert.AreEqual(true,InstanceA.Equals(InstanceB))` as this is sure to use your Equals method; of course this assumes you have unit-tested your Equals method and are 100% certain that it works :)

As to why Assert uses object.Equals, I guess we'd have to ask the designer of the class :) But I suppose one reason is that if your Equals method is buggy, your test result is no good.

Comment: I just ended up forwarding to the relevant functions in object.Equals by checking the input type. I was more asking why, rather than searching for a solution.